# Sharepoint 2010 Workflow - sending one email to different groups based on variable

Tags: 2010, workflow, email

I have an email that can go to a number of different parties, determined by one value in the form.  If the value is Department 1, the email goes to a, b, and c; if it's department 2, it goes to d,e, and f, department 3 may go to a, d, and g, etc.  Same email, only the people it's going to changes

The only way I know how to set that up is a series of if clauses, with a separate email built: If area = "department 1" email a,b,c; If area = "department 2" email d,e,f

That seems a bit wasteful since the email itself is identical save for the routing, even more so since I have over ten options.

So is there a slightly more elegant way to do it? load the email addresses into a value that I can feed to a single email object maybe?

Failing that, is there a way to copy and past steps in a workflow of which I'm unaware?  Cause then I wouldn't have to rebuild the whole email every time, just paste a copy of the step and update the To field.

Or of course, some other process I've not even considered.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions to get the to addresses and write one email action which will use the to addresses stored in the workflow variable.

Here are the steps.

**Create a workflow local variable**
[image]

**Update the workflow logic as follows**

Set the workflow variable with proper email addresses in the conditions.
[image]

This way you can maintain the common email action in one place.